# Time series with minutes interval

Tags: python, time-series

In time series forecasting for data with 5 minutes interval using autots module, I’m not getting the immediate future values rather I’m getting values after 11 months. Is there any way to solve this issue and get the immediate future values?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please, provide code example what you have done this far. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.